# Can't get access to logged in Google user in flutter code?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am new to flutter and Google-signin...I have the code working where it logs user in to both Google and FirebaseAuth. I am then trying, on other pages in the app, to reference the currently logged in Google user so I can access their authheaders in order to make a Google API call. I am able to access the their firebase instance by using the code below

Here I can easily access the currently logged in Firebase user.

```
     void setEmailAddress () {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((result) {
    _email = result.email;
  });
}
```

But, how can I access the current Google instance?? I've tried the following, but it's always null:

```
     void setEmailAddress () {
     GoogleSignInAccount _googleAccount = GoogleSignIn().currentUser;
    _emailFromGoogleAccount = _googleAccount.email;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of state management (like Provider or Redux) to set the google user on the root of your widget tree and then retrieve anywhere on your app.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out...you can use this, and as long as you are logged in, it gives a reference back to existing connection: GoogleSignIn si = GoogleSignIn();
    si.signInSilently().then((res){})